# Get the reduced opacity color of a layer in Photoshop

Tags: interface-design, photography

I have a layer which is completely filled with a color to which i am changing the opacity value to say some 80%. Is it possible to get the color code of the layer with the reduced opacity?

To put it more simple, i want to know what color will 80% of #555555 be.

Any possible ways in photoshop or in any other softwares ?

Answer (score 1):

You can, if you reduce the opacity to 80% of the layer and merge it with a blank layer this will be 100% again.

Thus using the color picker this will tell you what the color code for 80% is.

80% of #555555 is #777777

Also this question may help.

[Formula for finding out the result of a color after applying x-opacity to it](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2770/formula-for-finding-out-the-result-of-a-color-after-applying-x-opacity-to-it)

Comment: Remember that the resulting color from a layer with less than 100% opacity will depend on the color on the layer beneath.

Comment: Agreed @HenrikEkblom. This is the closest way I know non-mathematically.